# GPRS modem as TCP client final command not working

Tags: microcontroller, at-command, gprs

I have used the following sequence of command on a wavecom modem, so far I have determined that sending the last one seems to reset the device, while sending the others works fine. I have done it using a freescale jm128 micro controller. The funny thing is that if I do it using docklight it works perfectly. I think it resets because when communicating with the modem using docklight after the micro controller sends the whole sequence of commands, I find that it has ignored ATE and AT+CMEE=1, that is to say, I still get echo and don't get number codes for the errors. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
ATE //suppress echo
AT+CMEE=1//details on errors
AT+WIPCFG=1 //start IP stack
AT+WIPBR=1,6 //open GPRS bearer
AT+WIPBR=2,6,11,"APN" //set APN of GPRS bearer
AT+WIPBR=2,6,0 //username
AT+WIPBR=2,6,1 //password
AT+WIPBR=4,6,0 //start GPRS bearer
AT+WIPCREATE=2,1,"server_ip_address",server_port //create a TCP client on port "server_port"
AT+WIPDATA=2,1,1 //switch do data exchange mode
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved: First of all I changed the cable used to connect the modem with the microcontroller,
I used a db9, crossed 2 and 3 (rx and tx), put 4 and 7 pins to gnd, and didn't connect
pins 1, 8,9. Second, I changed at+wipdata= 2,1,1 to at+wipdata=2,1,2. It worked fine. I used
a Q2687 sierra wireless modem. Hope this helps someone who finds the same problems I found.